# AppStudio App not showing keyboard

Tags: windows-10-universal, microsoft-appstudio

I have created a very simple appstudio app on the microsoft website.  It is a web hosted app, so it is simple a container for a website.  However, whenever i click on a text field the keyboard does not automatically pop up.  I have tried with both mode on and off but to no avail.  It does work generally on websites so not sure if it is something to do the app itself.

Any help appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: can you provide a link to the app. with the very limited information you've provided, it is difficult to suggest any solutions.

Comment: thank you for your reply.  what is the best what to do this as all i have is a QR code.  The app is just a web hosted one for www.google.co.uk. I have run this app in both tablet and non tablet mode but the keyboard does not appear upon clicking the search bar.  (Sorry a newbie)